# T-SQL Query Performance - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query which is performing badly. It is taking about 2 minutes to return the result set.

Is there a better way to rewrite the query? I know about CTE, but never used it before.

Please help.

```
select 
    CustomerPK, 
    LocalID, 
    ExternalID, 
    EarnedDate, 
    QtyEarned, 
    QtyUsed, 
    Value, 
    ServerSerial, 
    LastLocationID,
    SVS.Description as Status, 
    SVS.PhraseID as StatusPhraseID,
    (select SUM(IsNull(QtyEarned,0)) - SUM(IsNull(QtyUsed,0)) 
     from SVHistory SVH2 with (NoLock) 
     where CustomerPK=18653237 and SVH2.LocalID = SVH.LocalID and SVH2.ServerSerial=SVH.ServerSerial
    ) as QtyAvail,
    AdminUserID, 
    ExpireDate, 
    PresentedCustomerID, 
    PresentedCardTypeID, 
    ResolvedCustomerID, 
    HHID, 
    Replayed, 
    ReplayedDate
from 
        SVHistory SVH with (NoLock) 
inner join 
        StoredValueStatus SVS with (NoLock) on SVS.StatusID=SVH.StatusFlag 
where 
    LastLocationID <> -8 
    and CustomerPK = 18653237 
    and SVProgramID = 112 
    and LastUpdate between '2013-05-27 00:00:00' and '2013-06-26 23:59:59' 
    and Deleted = 0 
order by 
    EarnedDate DESC, 
    LocalID, 
    ExternalID, 
    Status;
```

Comment: We need to know that your tables and indexes look like.

Comment: You should look at the **execution plan** (and possibly post it here) - it'll tell you where you're losing your time....

Comment: The is just strange.  You are reporting individual QtyEarned QtyUsed and AND for each line a sum of aggregate difference.

Comment: It's not strange; it's just denormalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    CustomerPK, 
    LocalID, 
    ExternalID, 
    EarnedDate, 
    QtyEarned, 
    QtyUsed, 
    Value, 
    ServerSerial, 
    LastLocationID,
    SVS.Description as Status, 
    SVS.PhraseID as StatusPhraseID,
    IsNull(SUM(QtyEarned) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerPK,LocalID,ServerSerial),0) -
      IsNull(SUM(QtyUsed) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerPK,LocalID,ServerSerial),0) as QtyAvail,
    AdminUserID, 
    ExpireDate, 
    PresentedCustomerID, 
    PresentedCardTypeID, 
    ResolvedCustomerID, 
    HHID, 
    Replayed, 
    ReplayedDate
from 
SVHistory SVH with (NoLock) 
inner join StoredValueStatus SVS with (NoLock) on SVS.StatusID=SVH.StatusFlag 
where 
    LastLocationID <> -8 
    and CustomerPK= 18653237 
    and SVProgramID=112 
    and LastUpdate between '2013-05-27 00:00:00' and '2013-06-26 23:59:59' 
    and Deleted=0 
order by 
    EarnedDate DESC, 
    LocalID, 
    ExternalID, 
    Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    CustomerPK, 
    LocalID, 
    ExternalID, 
    EarnedDate, 
    QtyEarned, 
    QtyUsed, 
    Value, 
    ServerSerial, 
    LastLocationID,
    SVS.Description as Status, 
    SVS.PhraseID as StatusPhraseID,
    netT.net,
    AdminUserID, 
    ExpireDate, 
    PresentedCustomerID, 
    PresentedCardTypeID, 
    ResolvedCustomerID, 
    HHID, 
    Replayed, 
    ReplayedDate
from 
        SVHistory SVH with (NoLock) 
inner join 
        StoredValueStatus SVS with (NoLock) on SVS.StatusID=SVH.StatusFlag
inner merge join  
   ( select LocalID, ServerSerial, SUM(IsNull(QtyEarned,0)) - SUM(IsNull(QtyUsed,0)) as net
     from SVHistory 
     where CustomerPK=18653237 
     group by LocalID, ServerSerial
   ) netT
  on netT.LocalID = SVH.LocalID 
 and netT.ServerSerial = SVH.ServerSerial
where 
    LastLocationID <> -8 
    and CustomerPK = 18653237 
    and SVProgramID = 112 
    and LastUpdate between '2013-05-27 00:00:00' and '2013-06-26 23:59:59' 
    and Deleted = 0
```

Comment: Spelling: "inner *merger* join"

Comment: @RBarryYoung I got inner right.  That syntax was clearly by hand and not tested.